# Showing injectivity of a real function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

> $g$ is a real function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $|g'|\leq M$. For given $\epsilon>0,$ define $f(x)=x+\epsilon g(x)$.

What I'm trying to show is the injectivity of $f$ for suitable $\epsilon$.

To do that, what I have to show is the implication $$f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y.$$

So, $$x+\epsilon g(x)=y+\epsilon g(y)\implies x-y=\epsilon (g(y)-g(x)).$$

And by the mean value theorem, $$g(y)-g(x)=g'(c)(y-x)$$ for some $c$ between $x,y$.

From the hypothesis $|g'|\leq M$, $$g(y)-g(x)\leq M(y-x).$$

Thus, $$x-y=\epsilon (g(y)-g(x))\leq \epsilon M(y-x).$$

If $x=y,$ the inequality holds trivially, nothing to prove. So we have to get a contradiction in the case $x\not=y.$ Suppose $x\not=y.$

1. $x>y\implies -1\geq \epsilon M>0$: a contradiction.
2. $x<y\implies$ divide both side of $x-y=\epsilon (g(y)-g(x))$ by $-\epsilon (y-x)\implies$ $$\frac{1}{\epsilon}=-\frac{g(y)-g(x)}{y-x}>0$$

So $g$ must be strictly decreasing; which is not included in the hypothesis. But I guess it's little bit weak to say "a contradiction".

Is this enough? or logically correct to finish to proof?

Comment: It should be $|g(y)-g(x)|\leq M|y-x|$, not $g(y)-g(x)\leq M(y-x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is not complete. Let $0<\epsilon <\frac 1 M$. let us show that $g$ is injective. Suppose $g(x)=g(y)$. Then $x-y=\epsilon (g(y)-g(x))=\epsilon (x-y)g'(t)$ for some $t$. Hence $|x-y| \leq \epsilon M |x-y|$. If $x \neq y$ this implies $1\leq \epsilon M $. This is a contradcition.